# How to better identify the location of these land forms?

Tags: translation

I've just posted the question [What produces these amazing 3D structures in Tibet?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16910/6031) in Earth Science SE with the screen shots below. I'm told that the area is called 札达土林 in Chinese, and that seems to be [Zanda County in Tibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zanda_County)

Is it possible to know if that location information is accurate? Is there a better way to identify the location where these images were taken?

I'd like to search further in order to eventually get some GPS coordinate so I can add to the linked question; "Zanda County in Tibet" is too large of an area pin down.

Screen shots from the video [航拍西藏 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tpws4xLMK7Y)

[image: 札达土林 Zanda County in Tibet]

[image: 札达土林 Zanda County in Tibet]

Comment: I understand that this is not the most defensibly on-topic question possible, but it's the limit of what research I can do. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if it's the same idea as Goblin Valley in southern Utah....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

札达土林 is not Zanda County, but rather the [Zhada Earth Forest National Geopark](https://www.tripadvisor.com.br/Attraction_Review-g1136581-d1871496-Reviews-Zhada_Earth_Forest_National_Geopark-Zanda_County_Tibet.html). Note that 札达 in Standard Mandarin pinyin is *Zhádá*, hence the English translation. The native Tibetan version, རྩ་མདའ, is transliterated with Wylie transliteration as *rtsa mda'*, and the spelling "Zanda" is an approximation of the modern Tibetan pronunciation.

土林 literally does translate to "Earth (as in soil, dirt) Forest", but refers to any "forest of rock formations". Other examples include the one in [Yuanmou, Yunnan](https://www.tripadvisor.com.hk/Attraction_Review-g1795777-d1801274-Reviews-Yuanmou_Earth_and_Forest_Scenic_Resort-Yuanmou_County_Yunnan.html).

Comment: Thank you for the speedy answer, and background information as well!

Comment: I added a link to your answer back into [the other question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16910/6031), I hope you don't mind.